# How to use multiple tabs via async IO in a loop?

Tags: node.js, multithreading, tabs, puppeteer

I'm trying to use a set amount of tabs to open and operate on these while waiting for network IO to speed up my crawling process for a domain.

I've solved the same issue in Go via worker pool listening on a channel but I'm nt sure how I can solve the same problem in Node.js and Puppeteer.

My guess is the looping via

```
async function nextPage() {
    try {
        for (var link of uncrawledLinks.keys()) {
            if (runningThreads < maxThreads) {
                var page = await browser.newPage();
                console.log("nextPage() # runningThreads: " + runningThreads + " #  uncrawledLinks.size: " + uncrawledLinks.size);
            //debugger;
            crawlPage(page, link);
        }
    }
```

that may create a problem when I increase "maxthreads" higher than 1 but I could't solve the issue till now.

The problem that occurs when I set it higher than 1 is that links get crawled twice (but not every link, only ~90% of the links) so that I get duplicates which makes the crawler unuseable.

I thought about using a DB like Redis or SQLite but I wanted to solve the problem first without it to understand the problem better (and till now I don't have a performance/memory problem so doing it in-memory is no problem).

Sample code that is runable:

```
'use strict';
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const url = require('url');

// start URL
const startUrlObj = url.parse("http://example.de/");
const startUrlDomain = startUrlObj.protocol + "//" + startUrlObj.hostname;
const startUrl = url.format(startUrlObj);

let browser;
let pages = [];
let uncrawledLinks = new Map();
let crawledLinks = [];
let runningThreads = 0;
const maxThreads = 1;

start();

async function start() {
    console.log("Starting Crawler");
    browser = await puppeteer.launch();
    console.log("Finished initializing browser object");
    uncrawledLinks.set(startUrl, "");
    nextPage();
};

async function crawlPage(page, link) {
    try {
        console.log("starting crawl for: " + link);
    runningThreads++;

    const response = await page.goto(link, {
        waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
        timeout: 30000
    });

    // find all links in the form <a href="xxx">
    const hrefs = await page.$$eval('a', as => as.map(a => a.href));
    hrefs.forEach(function(foundLink, key) {
        if (foundLink.startsWith(startUrlDomain)) {
            var tempUrl = url.parse(foundLink);
                // remove #asd and ?param1=y values from URL
                tempUrl.hash = null;
                tempUrl.search = null;
               var tempLink = url.format(tempUrl);
                //console.log(url.format(tempLink));
            if (crawledLinks.includes(tempLink) === false) {
                if (tempLink.endsWith(".html") === true) {
                    uncrawledLinks.set(tempLink, "false");
                    //pages.push(tempLink);
                }      
        }
    }},  hrefs)
    //console.log("Found new links: " + i + " # " + link);

    // crawling queues
    uncrawledLinks.delete(link);
    crawledLinks.push(link);

} catch (error) {
    // Log errors
    console.error(error);
} finally {
    runningThreads--;
    await page.close();
    await nextPage();
}

}

async function nextPage() {
    try {
        for (var link of uncrawledLinks.keys()) {
            if (runningThreads < maxThreads) {
                var page = await browser.newPage();
                //console.log("nextPage() # runningThreads: " + runningThreads + " #  uncrawledLinks.size: " + uncrawledLinks.size);
            //debugger;
            crawlPage(page, link);
        }
    }


} catch (error) {
    console.error(error);
} finally {
    if (uncrawledLinks.size === 0 && runningThreads === 0) {
        console.log("Finished crawling");
        console.log(crawledLinks);
        await browser.close();
    }
} 
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found out that one has to wrap the IO stuff with a Promise because only a Promise gives asynchron IO.

```
async function crawlPage(page, link) {
    browser.newPage().then(
        async page => {
            try {
                await page.setRequestInterception(true);
                // catch all requests
                page.on('request', request => {

                })

                await page.goto(uncrawledUrl, {
                    waitUntil: 'networkidle2',
                    timeout: 10000
                }).then(
                    async response => {
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, unfortunately (or fortunately, depending on your point of view) you don't have threads in Node.js (technically you have but they are not available from the JavaScript code - only on the C++ level). This is just to make it clear because it may be an innocent naming error or a misunderstanding that might give you unreasonable expectations.

Second of all, note that you are catching `erorr` but printing `error` so you may have some errors that are not visible because of the variable misspelling.

And finally, what you are trying to do (async operations in parallel with a limit of how many outstanding operations there are in any given time) can be quite easily solved with `eachLimit` method from Bluebird:

- https://caolan.github.io/async/docs.html#eachLimit

This is not easily done with a simple loop with `async` keyword because by using `async` in a loop you are stopping the iteration until the promise is resolved, not doing other iterations in parallel, and you'd have to manually track the counter but by `awaiting` on the state of the counter changes and not on the given function invocations. Certainly easier to do with the `async` module, not the `async` keyword.

Comment: Just naming error. "erorr" fixed. async module doesn't seem to be compatible with Puppeteer, I get "
TypeError: page.setRequestInterception is not a function".

       async.eachLimit(uncrawledLinks.keys(), 1, function(link, callback) {
            id++;
            var page = browser.newPage();
            var myPage = new Object();
            runningThreads++;
            crawlPage(page, myPage, link, id);
       }, function(err, data) {
        if (uncrawledLinks.size === 0 && runningThreads === 0) {
            console.log(pages);
            browser.close();
        } });